# Extract image from video, image color is different swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetimagegenerator

I capture video using `AVCaptureSession` session preset is

```
session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
```

and extract image from video using this code

```
func videoThumbnails(url: NSURL ){
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    imageGenerator.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(720, 1280)
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero

    var time = asset.duration
    let totalTime = time
    var frames = 0.0
    let singleFrame = Double(time.seconds) / 4
    while (frames < totalTime.seconds) {
        frames += singleFrame
        time.value = (Int64(frames)) * Int64(totalTime.timescale)
        do {

            let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)

            self.sendImage.append(UIImage(CGImage: imageRef))
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")

        }
    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCapturedImages", sender: nil)

}
```

Now you can check image above the video so that you can check color difference.

[image]

Now what I want is extract exact image from video. how to do?

Comment: It just seems a part of the UI of your application

Comment: No its not. I extract the image from video and just show it above the video with exact position using UIImage above AVPlayerViewController. and when I export the video it is still the same with that color issue.

Comment: There are plenty of possible causes: the inner image is resized to fit the area, how you set the camera ( the frames are usually in YUV but probably it converts to RGB), compression etc

Comment: so, how to resolve this thing.?